# How to autofocus/autoclick paper-input in polymer 1.0?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I was able to use javascript and call .click() or .focus() in order to have the paper-input ready for typing in polymer 0.5.6.

1.0 seems to have lost this ability. Is there a way to have the input ready to type either using JS or by using the new 1.0 Polymer API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation at https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=Polymer.PaperInputBehavior this should work:

```
<paper-input autofocus></paper-input>
```

Comment: it used to be "focus".. i guess they changed it to "autofocus" now.

Comment: actually i have 2 paper inputs (one in header) for a search engine. and it defaults the autofocus to the header one when both have "autofocus". 

The header bar is hidden on the homepage. Any way to autofocus the main search bar (non-header) only?

Comment: That sounds pretty tricky, you'll probably want to post that as a new question along with the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set focus from code (perhaps to respond to a user action) these two code snippets may help.

To set focus to the first paper-input you can use this:

```
$('paper-input input').first().focus();
```

you can also select by id for a specific paper-input:

```
$('#myValue input').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript:

```
var textbox = document.getElementById("myInputBox");
textbox.focus();
tetbox.scrollIntoView();
```

if this doesnt work, then you might be setting the focus later on in your implementation to something else?

Answer (score 0):

As a firefox user, I wanted this to just work (like it does in Chrome):

```
    <paper-input autofocus></paper-input>
```

but no dice. So I tried:

```
    var textbox = document.getElementById("myInputBox");
    textbox.focus();
```

which logs "TypeError: textbox is null" to the console...I'm guessing because the shady DOM loads after the not-so-shady DOM.

So it looks like the autofocus tag's functionality depends on the browser in which the app runs. Hopefully this changes with future releases. In the meantime, better documentation would be nice.